# How to use jQuery in document body?

Tags: jquery, html

I have written jQuery code in the head tag using:

```
$(document).ready(function{
     .....
});
```

and it works fine.
After that I have added another jQuery code in the body but it doesn't work. My question is how to use jQuery in the body? And can I use:

```
$(document).ready(...)
```

more than one time in the head and in the body again?
my code is :

```html
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
     $(function(){
             $.ajax({
             url: 'ajax/game.php';,
             type: 'POST',
             data: {'do':'favorite','gameid':'".$gameId."'},
             beforeSend: function(){
                           alert('work');
                         },
       success:function(){
                       alert('Done');
                     }
             });
     });
</script>";
```

Comment: You'll need to show the code that doesn't work for anyone to be able to tell what's wrong with it.

Comment: You have got the definition of a client side scripting language all wrong. Why do you want to use the jQuery in the body when the head is made for that purpose?

Comment: doesn't matter the code all the javascript codes and jQuery codes doesn't work

Comment: my question is how to put jQuery codes in the body ?

Comment: Of course it matters! There's a million reasons why code might not work. Unless someone here can read your mind there's no way to know why *your* code might not work.

Comment: i have added my code !

Comment: This has nothing to do with the script's placement. There's an extra semicolon in `url: 'ajax/game.php';,`  (should be `url: 'ajax/game.php',`). In the future you should use the browser's error console to see syntax errors thrown by the JS code.

Answer (score -1):

When using `$(document).ready()`, you want your code to be executed once the whole document (DOM) has been loaded ([.ready() in jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)).

In order for a page to be displayed more quickly, it's common practice to put the code at the end of your `<body>` element. The code should be surrounded by the `<script>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function{
     .....
});
</script>
```

You can include `$(document).ready()` [as many times as you wish](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/multiple-document-ready), both in the `<head>` as well as at the end of the `<body>` tag. However, this might not be best practice. It all depends on what you're trying to achieve and how exactly you're going about it.